How to convert from string to 8-bit binary number and vice versa
I have a letter, for example, the letter s. I want to convert it to a binary 8-bit string and back. I have read many articles, but I don't really understand. Can someone help me?

You can use ord(), chr() and int():
def _bin(char):
    return format(ord(char), '08b')


def _int(b):
    return chr(int(b, 2))


print(_bin('A'))
print(_int('01000001'))


Prints
01000001
A

Comment
@SIGHUP: Use of format() is functionally correct but most modern code would probably use f-strings - e.g., return f"{ord(char):08b}".

Use of format() is functionally correct but most modern code would probably use f-strings - e.g., return f"{ord(char):08b}"
